# Pass Value from Code Behind to JavaScript Function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Below is my JavaScript Function

```
function HighlightWord(highlightword) {
       alert(highlightword);
}
```

When I pass value to above function using below code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", "HighlightWord(abc)", true);
```

alert displays 'undefined'. What is wrong in this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", "HighlightWord(abc)", true);
```

means alert the `abc` variable which I assume you don't have. It should be

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", "HighlightWord('abc')", true);`.
```

This will alert "abc" which is what I assume you want to happen.